# RxJS5: .combineLatest() with projection function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, reactivex

I need a way to pipe values from an observable to two functions that each accept a value and each in turn returns an observable (emiting only a single value, then completing). I was hoping `.combineLatest()` would allow me to pass a projection function, but it doesn't.

Sample code (not working):

```
const ac = [1, 2, 3]; // only as example, I have complex types in my array not numbers

Observable.from(ac)
    .combineLatest(
        // processFn should get a number as argument and return Observable<number>
        // does not work because .combineLatest does not accept two functions as arguments :(
        n => processFn1(n),
        n => processFn2(n)
    )
    .map(([result1, result2] => {
        // result1, result2 should be flat numbers here, not Observables
    })
);
```

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea to use the combineLatest operator is correct but it's in the wrong place. If you need to flat out observables you should be using mergeMap. This is a JSBIN that does what you expect: http://jsbin.com/rutovot/4/edit?html,js,console

The code looks like this:

```
const ac = [1, 2, 3];

Rx.Observable.from(ac)
  // use mergeMap, it takes a function that accepts a value and
  // returns an observable. MergeMap will listen to this observable
  // under the hood and next the result of this observable down the
  // the chain
  .mergeMap(val => {
    // Here we return an observable that combines the result of the
    // call to both the functions
    return Rx.Observable.combineLatest(fake(val), fake2(val));
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Often is with RxJS but it takes some time to get use to it :)